# PHP function to return a reference a variable

Tags: php, reference, variables, return

I'm trying to write a function that will return a reference to a PDO object. The reason for wanting a reference is if, for some reason, the PDO object gets called twice in one page load, it will just return the same object rather than initializing a new one. This isn't silly, is it? :/

```
function &getPDO()
{
   var $pdo;

   if (!$pdo)
   {
      $pdo = new PDO...

      return $pdo;
   }
   else
   {
      return &pdo;
   }
}
```

Something like that

Comment: `return &$pdo;` is a syntax error. You should do `return $pdo;`. The `&` sign is only used in the function declaration and not when you return it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `static $pdo;`.

```
function getPDO()
{
   static $pdo;

   if (!$pdo)
   {
      $pdo = new PDO...
   }

   return $pdo;

}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and all you other guys below this comment for the help. So that function will return a reference to the variable without the need for the ampersand?

Comment: @dave, without the ampersand it will not return a *reference*. What it returns is a copy of the object identifier http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 2):

Objects are *always* passed by reference in PHP. For example:

```
class Foo {
  public $bar;
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar = 3;
myfunc($foo);
echo $foo->bar; // 7

function myfunc(Foo $foo) {
  $foo->bar = 7;
}
```

It's only non-objects (scalars, arrays) that are passed by value. See [References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

In relation to your function, you need to make the variable static. `var` is deprecated in PHP 5. So:

```
function getFoo() {
  static $foo;
  if (!$foo) {
    $foo = new Foo;
  }
  return $foo;
}
```

No ampersand required.

See [Objects and references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) as well.

Comment: **Not true**, what is passed is a copy of their identifier and not a reference. The link you linked explains in the first para...

Answer (score 1):

To make a reference to a variable `$foo`, do this:

```
$bar =& $foo;
```

Then `return` $bar.

Answer (score 0):

You would write it like this

```
function getPDO()
{
   static $pdo;

   if (!$pdo) {
      $pdo = new PDO...
   }

   return $pdo;
}
```